# How to turn on home server when any one of the computers in the home network is on?

Tags: home-server

To save energy, I want to have my home server on **only** when one of the computers in my house are on. What's the best way of automating this?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by `home server`?  A PC on a wireless connection?  A NAS on a wired LAN?  What is it?

Comment: If it's a normal PC you may have some luck with wake-on-lan/magic packets to turn it on automatically.

Comment: My home server is an ubuntu machine that serves mainly as a backup server.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the server to go to sleep after a few minutes of inactivity and to use [Wake-on-Lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) (WOL).

If you want more details on how to do this, you will need to provide us more information about your server.